# How to solve this rate of speed question

Tags: linear-algebra

Two cars start from the same point, one at 12pm and other at 2pm and travel towards the same destination. Car B (which started at 2pm) travels 20mph faster than car A. Car B arrives at a destination 1000miles away 25min before car A. Assuming their speeds are constant, calculate the individual speeds.

Comment: mph = Miles per Hour

Comment: Have you tried anything? Even a simple graph showing the two cars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$v_B=v_A+20$.

Think about the problem this way:

$A$ has a head start of $2v_A$ miles and only then both $A$ and $B$ begin driving.

For $A$ it takes $\frac{1000-2v_A}{v_A}$ hours to get to the place.

For $B$ it takes $\frac{1000-2v_A}{v_A}-\frac{25}{60}$ hours to get to the place.

But the place is $1000$ miles away, so

$$(v_A+20)\left(\frac{1000-2v_A}{v_A}-\frac{25}{60}\right)=1000$$

Now solve the equation.

Comment: how did you get `10` in `10(va + 20)`?

Comment: @MessedUpMyHEAD $12\text{ PM}-2\text{ PM}=10\text{ PM}$.

Comment: I think you have mixed up `A` and `B` here cause `A` is the one who gets the head start but I do get the gist. Thanks! :)

Comment: @MessedUpMyHEAD But your question says that $B$ started at $2\text{ PM}$, which is $10$ hours earlier than $A$.

Comment: Err.. 2pm is 2 hours after 12pm. So its supposed to be `2(Va + 20)` :)

Comment: @MessedUpMyHEAD I've edited the answer.

Comment: @MessedUpMyHEAD I'm sorry for confusing you - my later edit was wrong. Now it's correct.